# commerce coinbase wbhook payload error nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, coinbase-api

getting error "Error occured Invalid payload provided. No JSON object could be decoded"

i am using below code for webhook

```
 exports.paymentHandler = async (req, res) => {  
const rawBody = req.rawBody;
const signature = req.headers['x-cc-webhook-signature'];
 console.log("rawbody       ",rawBody)
try {
  const event = Webhook.verifyEventBody(rawBody, signature, webhookSecret);
  functions.logger.info(event);

  if (event.type === 'charge:pending') {
    // TODO
    // user paid, but transaction not confirm on blockchain yet
     console.log("pending payment");
  }

  if (event.type === 'charge:confirmed') {
    // TODO
    // all good, charge confirmed
     console.log("charge confirme");
  }

  if (event.type === 'charge:failed') {
    // TODO
    // charge failed or expired
    console.log("charge failed");
  }

  res.send(`success ${event.id}`);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).send("failure");
}
```

};

what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

For Node.js app to get rawBody from Coinbase use this code.

```
//server file
//app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.json({
        verify: (req, res, buf) => {
          req.rawBody = buf
        }
    }))
```

Now the raw body is available on `req.rawBody` and the JSON parsed data is available on `req.body`.

Usage:

```
const payloadRaw = req.rawBody
```